# Step response RC Circuit problem

Tags: homework

(Example problem from a textbook) A unit step function u(t) is added between the terminals 1-1'. I am asked to find the voltage vo(t) between 2-2'.

[image]

If we convert the circuit above to a s-domain circuit we get

[image]

According to the answers Vo(s) becomes

[image]

I understand that when we convert RC circuits to s-domain circuits the capacitors convert to 1/(Cs) and we need to add a voltage  V/s to them.

[image]

What is the meaning behind this 10^4/s? Does it somehow become like a resistor since you can connect it with other resistors in series?

Edit: this was an example problem from a textbook, whose authors chose to solve this problem using the s-domain. I just did not understand the s-domain part of the problem and that is why I did not post the remaining part.

Comment: Usually when we talk about s-parameters we're talking about the RF or microwave [scattering parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters). What you're asking about is the s-domain or Laplace transform domain. They're very different concepts, that only coincidentally both use the letter 's' for an important variable.

Comment: Question is not clear. 10^4/s is 1/cs. V0 is 0V at t=0. So, V0/s term is not there. So, what is the confusion? BTW, to find Vo(t), isn't it easier to just do it in time domain?

Comment: I didn't realize that. Let me edit the post then

Comment: I do not understand what you really want.  In the 1st line you speak about the timely response Vo(t) and then you want to "convert RC circuits to s.domain" ?? And you end up with Vo(s) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I do not understand is how the 100uF cap became 10^4/s.

\$100\ {\rm\mu F}\$ is \$100\times10^{-6}\ {\rm F}\$, or \$10^{-4}\ {\rm F}\$.

And \$\frac{1}{10^{-4}}\$ is \$10^4\$.

> Does it somehow become like a resistor since you can connect it with other resistors in series?

Not exactly, a resistor in the s-domain has no \$s\$ in its value.

But in the Laplace or s-domain you can do math on the impedances of capacitors and inductors to evaluate series and parallel combinations in a way that's analogous to how you evaluate series and parallel combinations of resistors in the DC stead state.